# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "App-component" is not a valid custom element name

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста. Я пытался сделать собственную компоненту но что-то пошло не так

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hello world!</h1>

    <App-component> Wtf is this! </App-component>

    <script type='module' src='index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
class AppComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this._name = 'AppComponent';
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert(`Hello, ${this._name}`);
        });
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (attrName === 'name') {
            if (newValue) {
            this._name = newValue;
            } else {
            this._name = 'AppComponent';
            }
        }
    }
}

AppComponent.observedAttributes = ['name'];
customElements.define('App-component', AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
customElements.define('app-component', AppComponent);
```

```
<app-component>...</app-component>
```

Согласно [спецификации HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name), имя кастомного элемента не может содержать латинские символы в верхнем регистре, и обязательно должно начинаться с латинского символа в нижнем регистре.